# After execute git filter-branch command then it was showing duplicate commit in Android Studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I am facing issue in Git branches after filter-branch command execute and it was showing duplicate commits as per below screenshot attached.

I have changed the wrong email to correct email as per below git filter-branch command. And how to remove duplicate commit?

```
git filter-branch --env-filter '
WRONG_EMAIL="pratik@google.com"
NEW_NAME="Pratik"
NEW_EMAIL="pratik@gmail.com"

if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = "$WRONG_EMAIL" ]
then
    export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$NEW_NAME"
    export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$NEW_EMAIL"
fi
if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "$WRONG_EMAIL" ]
then
    export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$NEW_NAME"
    export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$NEW_EMAIL"
fi
' --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches --tags
```

[image]

Comment: This is normal: filter-branch (like any "history rewrite" operation in Git) works by *copying* commits to new commits that, presumably, you like better than the original commits. You *must not* re-introduce the original commits. The new `git filter-repo` command (not yet included in Git distributions) makes this clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The point of running `git filter-branch` is to rewrite the history. You should not merge the results back with what's on origin, or do a `git pull`, but rather you need to do a force push of the rewritten history on origin.

At this point, you're probably going to want to do a `git reset --hard <sha1>` to point your local branch back to the result of the filter-branch, i.e., undo that merge (I would guess the merge happened when you pulled), and then once you've done all the necessary safety checks and warned you team, do your forced push: `git push -f origin <branch-name>`.

The warnings to your collaborators are important: if anyone has working branches from any of the commits you're replacing in the history, you'll want to make sure they don't do a git pull or any other merges that bring the duplicate commits back in! After a filter-branch, all future work has to start from the new history.